# Баг flask/uwsgi/nginx, отображает старые версии страницы после новых изменений

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, flask, vps, uwsgi

Здравствуйте. Установил на VPS/VDS (Ubuntu) связку nginx/uwsgi/flask.
Работает. Вот только заметил один надоедливый баг: в Flask-приложении страницу index.html отдаю при помощи render_template, если изменить документ (index.html в моем случае), то изменения отобразятся на странице после нескольких ее перезагрузок, но.. после последующих перезагрузок с шансом 50% показывает старые версии страницы (все сохраняемые в редакторе версии, после перезагрузки systemctl restart web-site). После перезагрузки

### Пример

### [image: баг]

*/srv/web-site/**application.py***

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

*/srv/web-site/**uwsgi.ini***

```
[uwsgi]
module = application:app
master = true
processes = 5
socket = /tmp/web-site.sock
chmod-socket = 664
chown-socket = web-site:www-data
uid = web-site
gid = www-data
logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log
vacuum = true
die-on-term = true
```

*/etc/systemd/system/**web-site.service***

```
[Unit]
Description=web-site server.
After=network.target

[Service]
User=web-site
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/srv/web-site
Environment="PATH=/srv/web-site/venv/bin"
ExecStart=/srv/web-site/venv/bin/uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*/etc/nginx/sites-avaible/**web-site.conf***

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80 ipv6only=on;
    server_name web-site-ip;

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/web-site.sock;
    }
}
```

После перезагрузки сервиса web-site.service, предыдущие версии перестает показывать.
Подскажите в чем может быть проблема, какое есть решение.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Позвольте уточнить: ваш сайт запущен как systemd-служба `web-site` с uwsgi внутри, и даже если её перезапустить, то всё равно иногда отдаётся старый шаблон?

Comment: Да. Сайт запущен как systemd-служба, но если ее перезапустить, то перестает отдавать старые, относительно момента перезагрузки.

Comment: Если после перезапуска всё нормально, то вроде так и должно быть, фласк что-то там кэширует

Comment: Очень странно, фласк, по идеи, должен отправлять самую новую версию страницы, но не позапрошлую и не позапозапрошлую.

Comment: Фласк никому ничего не должен, потому что шаблоны не принято менять во время работы сервера :)

Answer (score 1):

Браузеры обычно кешируют статику страниц сайтов, в вашем случае происходит именно это - если хотите увидеть изменения сразу же после правки кода - перезапустите nginx и gunicorn (или что у вас там вместо этого) на сервере, а у себя в браузере обновите страницу, нажав Ctrl+F5 .